# Main domain subdomain htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a domain called www.abc123.com.

after public_html/, I have a folder called portfolio which runs everything for www.abc123.com

Using this htaccess after public_html/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ portfolio/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(\d+)(_m_\d+)?\.([^\.]+)$    $1.$4    [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

So when www.abc123.com is visited it will run portfolio/index.php with a clean url of www.abc123.com .

Now Ive added a subdomain called coolstuff now my file manager looks like this

```
public_html/
    cgi-bin/
    portfolio/
    coolstuff/index.html
```

now everytime I go to **coolstuff.abc123.com/index.html** i get 500 Internal Server Error.
If I take out my htaccess then **coolstuff.abc123.com/index.html** will show and
**www.abc123.com** will show anchor tags of my cgi-bin,portfolio,coolstuff.

I need:

- www.abc123.com to read portfolio/index.php and keep url (www.abc123.com)
- and coolstuff.abc123.com/index.html to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} abc123
RewriteRule ^$ portfolio/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} abc123
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} abc123
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(\d+)(_m_\d+)?\.([^.]+)$ $1.$4 [L]
```